# How to import BeautifulSoup into a python method OpenERP 7 module

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup, openerp-7

I'm trying to use BeautifulSoup method inside my module method. If I import as `from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup` that is working in while running python through CMD
   How can I import BeautifulSoup3 library that I installed in python 2.7 into my OpenERP module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just copy and paste the BeautifullSoup.py file from python27\Lib\site-packages\BeautifullSoup.py into the folder path openERP7>Server>server and it will do the trick.